# Is it possible to play and record audio at the same time not using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

The idea comes from this app (Keezy) : http://keezy.net/

Basically, I'm trying to allow a user to listen to audio and record at the same time. I am aware of the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, BUT this category forces the volume of the `AVAudioPlayer` to be reduced heavily.

Trying to record audio while at the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` does not work (doesn't record anything) and the other categories don't seem relevant. I'm wondering if there is way to achieve what is done in Keezy - audio playback at high volume while allowing a user to record audio at the same time.

(Couldn't find any examples/topics about that solve this without the playback category.)

Answer (score 9):

Although the solution still involved the PlayAndRecord category, what needed to be added was the "AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker" to the category options - that allowed the audio to be played at normal volume and record as well.

Example:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```